# Kafka Partition is null

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am using spring kafka template to write messages to a kafka topic, and following API is used for publishing messages.

`public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(String topic, K key, @Nullable V data) {...    }`

The good thing about using this API is that it returns a sendResult object which has some metadata like topic, partition, headers etc. I have a callback which prints the sendResult upon onSuccess. Now the issue is, the partition is being printed as null.

Instead of call back, I tried changing this to
`future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` 
to get the sendResult. Even then the partition is printed as null. Can anyone pls let me kow what could be the reason for this? Is this a default behaviour of kafka?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to take a look for that info in the `SendResult.getRecordMetadata()` instead of `getProducerRecord()`.

The `ProducerRecord` is not modified by the `KafkaProducer`. So, the API you use is ended up like this:

```
public ListenableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> send(String topic, K key, @Nullable V data) {
    ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>(topic, key, data);
    return doSend(producerRecord);
}
```

Where the `partition` property of the `ProducerRecord` is indeed `null`.

The `RecordMetadata`, on another hand, is indeed built already after the server answer.
You can get a required info from its `partition()` option.

Comment: Right `SendResult [producerRecord=ProducerRecord(topic=topic-1, partition=null, headers=RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = true), key=null, value=foo, timestamp=null), recordMetadata=topic-1-0@0]`.

Comment: @Artem Bilen the partition method in RecordMetaData is printing the topic indeed. Thanks a lot.